# add click listener to image button in Recycle view row

Tags: android

I using recycle view and i have in each row textview and image button.
In on bind i adding to the image button click listener but when i try to click on the image button it clicks on the row and react only when i long click on the image button.

Any suggestions?

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final FolderViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    if (isFolder(position)) {
        holder.folderName.setText(folders.get(position));

    }else{

        ImageButton edit = (ImageButton) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.browser_bookmark_row_edit);
        edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println(" ######### EDIT CLICKED");
                mListener.switchToEditBookmarkFragmentFolderAdapter(bookmarks.get(position - folders.size()));
            }
        });

        holder.folderName.setText(bookmarks.get(position - folders.size() ).getTitle());
    }

}




public class FolderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    MuseoSansTextView folderName;
    View view;

    public FolderViewHolder(View itemView, MuseoSansTextView museoSansTextView) {
        super(itemView);

        view = itemView;
        folderName = museoSansTextView; //(MuseoSansTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.browser_bookmark_folder_name);

    }

}



<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:id="@+id/card_view_contact"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/transparent"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">


        <com.osnewhorizon.pommmanager.ui.MuseoSansTextView
            android:id="@+id/browser_bookmark_row_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/browser_bookmark_row_edit"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="test"
            android:textSize="@dimen/contact_row_title_height" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/browser_bookmark_row_edit"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/edit"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: provide the implementation of FolderViewHolder Class.

Comment: also provide the xml file row item.

Comment: Added the xml of the row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the problem. Because my recycle view have in addition touch listener in the fragment itself, he catches the click event.

Answer (score 3):

First, you create an interface like :

```
public interface OnItemClickListener{
      void onItemClick(View view, int position)
}
```

Declare on global :

```
private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;
```

Next, you need a contructor like :

```
public MyAdapter(Context context, List data, OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener){
    //...
    this.mOnItemClickListener= mOnItemClickListener;

}
```

And in `onBindViewHolder`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final FolderViewHolder holder, final int position) {
      //....
      holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnItemClickListener){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(v,position);    
            }
        });
}
```

Finally, you can implement Callback in class use adapter like :

```
public class A extends AppCombatActivity implements MyAdapter.OnItemClickListener{
//exist code
   @Override
   onItemClick(View view, int position){
       // Do something with view + position
   }
//


}
```

P.s : With solution this, you can catch multi events child view in row :)

Comment: Thank for trying to help, my current implementation the onClick event work but for some reason on long click. i think it some element is blocking the imageButton listener

Comment: If you want handle event long click, you can catch event long click by view.setLongClickListener(...)

Comment: No, my problem is i set regular onClick but it triggers only when i long press the image, like some thing catch the event before the image

Comment: Sorry... I'm not very good at English :)... I'm reading question but don't understand :))

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to your `root view` in xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <Button
     ... 
       />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Or you can use `ImageView` instead of `ImageButton`.

Comment: I am using "blocksDescendants" and tried ImageButton and ImageView no success

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using imageButton , use imageView instead

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **android:clickable="true"** in your xml layout which was inflated as a row.

Comment: To the image button?

Comment: yes, to the imagbutton. sometimes image button click event may be overridden by recyclerview row item click event.

Answer (score 0):

please find imageButton xml view in Constructor like and
Set your **ImageButton** click listener in  FolderViewHolder Constructor below.

```
public FolderViewHolder(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);
    imageButton=(ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.browser_bookmark_row_edit)
     imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println(" ######### EDIT CLICKED");
            mListener.switchToEditBookmarkFragmentFolderAdapter(bookmarks.get(getAdapterPosition()) - folders.size()));
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: Where you saw i adding click listener to the hole itemView? and your code not work as well

Comment: can you provide the xml file content of row item.

Comment: Added the xml of the row

Comment: no it doesn't work. even after using switch case for Ids , when i click on imageButton it triggers action of both 1st - Row View action is called due to itemView.setOnClickListener then 2nd - ImageButtons' action is called.

One solution i found handle with Row clicks in your Parent Activity (where you are using RecyclerView) and handle items click inside onBindViewHolder inside RecyclerAdapter class. Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In `RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener`, `onSingleTapUp()` returned `true`. It should be `false`. So click event executed that will present in holder view in `onBindViewHolder()`.